# non-sudo perf sched always fails with "broken or missing trace data"

Tags: ubuntu, perf

On my Ubuntu 22.04 (5.19.0-35-generic), it seems that `perf sched` is not able to parse its own `perf.data` output. Following the examples on [Brendan Gregg's blog](https://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2017-03-16/perf-sched.html), recording works fine

```
# perf sched record -- sleep 1
[ perf record: Woken up 1 times to write data ]
[ perf record: Captured and wrote 2.844 MB perf.data (11439 samples) ]
```

However, any my attempt at reading the profiling data fails:

```
# perf script --header
incompatible file format (rerun with -v to learn more)
```

```
# perf sched script
incompatible file format (rerun with -v to learn more)
```

```
# perf sched latency
incompatible file format (rerun with -v to learn more)
```

```
# perf sched map
incompatible file format (rerun with -v to learn more)
```

The verbose output just tells `broken or missing trace data`:

```
# perf script -v --header
build id event received for [kernel.kallsyms]: 77ab8542b6540fae3367bbb18a7aeede3c3b6f7b [20]
build id event received for [vdso]: f33b8f26bed889157b75129711599f9ca5ec9d0e [20]
broken or missing trace data
incompatible file format (rerun with -v to learn more)
```

Googling a bit, I only found [old bug reports](https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-perf-users/msg02113.html), but their workarounds don't apply to my case:

```
# perf script --header -i - < perf.data
incompatible file format (rerun with -v to learn more)
```

Furthermore, I found that running the same commands with `sudo` works fine:

```
# sudo perf sched record -- sleep 1
[ perf record: Woken up 1 times to write data ]
[ perf record: Captured and wrote 3.875 MB perf.data (19424 samples) ]
```

```
# sudo perf script --header
<output>
```

Any clue what's the issue with the non-sudo commands?

Comment: I'm running a custom kernel 6.3.8, with custom built perf and getting the same behavior. Running via sudo works fine, but running as non-sudo causes the incompatible file format issue. Did OP figure this out?

Comment: To add, this behavior is happening for tracepoint related recording. (Not for SW events)

Comment: "Did OP figure this out?" - No, I used sudo and eventually moved away from `perf sched`.